# Why the following assembly code doesn't print out the new line (0xa) character?

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, x86-64

In the code below, NASM runs everything as expected, except for printing a new line character at the end. what could be the reason?

```
%define sys_write       0x2000004           ; system call number for write
%define sys_read        0x2000003           ; system call number for read
%define sys_exit        0x2000001           ; system call number for exit
%define std_out         0x1                 ; file descriptor number for standard output
%define std_in          0x2                 ; file descriptor number for standard input
%define new_line        0xa                 ; a new line character
%define current_address $                   ; address of current location

; a macro to implement the write system call and write
; a string into standard output using two parameters
%macro write_string 2
    mov rax, sys_write                          ; system call to write
    mov rdi, std_out                            ; standard output
    mov rsi, %1                                 ; a string to write
    mov rdx, %2                                 ; length of the string
    syscall                                     ; kernel call interruption
%endmacro

; a macro to implement the exit system call
%macro exit 0
    mov rax, sys_exit                           ; system call to exit
    syscall
%endmacro

    section .data

message:    db 'Displaying 9 stars', new_line       ; a message
.length:    equ current_address - message           ; length of the message
asterisks:  times 9 db '*'                          ; a string of 9 asterisks

global start

    section .text

start:                                      ; linker entry point

    write_string message, message.length    ; print a message to standard output
    write_string asterisks, 9               ; print 9 asterisks
    write_string new_line, 1                ; print a line feed(new line)

    exit                                    ; end the program
```

after assembling:

```
user$ nasm -f macho64 9stars.asm
user$ ld 9stars.o -o 9stars
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.10
user$ ./9stars
```

the expected output should be:

```
Displaying 9 stars
*********
user$
```

but the current output is:

```
Displaying 9 stars
*********user$
```

It looks like `write_string new_line, 1` does not treat `new_line` as a character constant
although in `db 'Displaying 9 stars', new_line` the `new_line` adds a new line character,
the character code 10. My initial guess is that `new_line` isn't a character constant at all.
What could be the reason for this? How could this be fixed? I'm on Mac OS X 10.10. I have
a core i5 m540 Intel CPU. I use NASM version 2.11.06.

Comment: Doesn't mac use `CR` (code `13`)?

Comment: @Jester: it did in "classic" Mac OS, up to around the year 2000. Mac OS X is essentially *nix though, and so it uses LF (0xa), as nature intended.

Comment: If you use `0xd` for new_line you will get the `*********user$` output and `Displaying 9 stars` won't print. It's because CR returns cursor to the first position (on the left) thus deleting `Displaying 9 stars`, unlike LF that feeds one line, moving the cursor one line down.

Comment: `%define std_in   0x2` should be `0`.  FD 2 is stderr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`write_string` expects the *address* of a string, but `new_line` is just the *character value* `0xa`. Trying to interpret this as the address of a string will give unpredictable results. If you want a string that just contains a single `0xa` that you can print then you'd need to do something like this:

```
    section .data

message:    db 'Displaying 9 stars', new_line       ; a message
.length:    equ current_address - message           ; length of the message
asterisks:  times 9 db '*'                          ; a string of 9 asterisks
newline:    db new_line                             ; <<< a single LF

global start

    section .text

start:                                      ; linker entry point

    write_string message, message.length    ; print a message to standard output
    write_string asterisks, 9               ; print 9 asterisks
    write_string newline, 1                 ; <<< print LF
```

Comment: Actaully, its pretty predictable -- 0xa is not going to be a valid address, so the system call will fail with EFAULT and not print anything.  Since he doesn't check for errors on the system call, it does nothing.

Comment: That's true, so I should be passing an address of a string, not a character value. (+1) I realize my mistake now. but If I use `newline:    db new_line                             ; <<< a single LF` It would defeat my initial purpose, which was to define a meaningful constant string that could be used through out the code. In order to eliminate the need to `newline:    db new_line`, which looks redundant, can I make `new_line: db 0xa` and use it instead? then how can I use it to make the `message`? since `message:    db 'Displaying 9 stars', new_line` won’t work after `new_line: db 0xa`

Comment: Normally you would just use `new_line` as part of any string you define (just like you did for `message`). For a single new_line on its own though there is nothing wrong with using the string `newline` as above - you only need to define this once of course and you can then use it everywhere. Alternatively consider implementing a `write_char` macro, which just outputs a single character value, then you can just do `write_char new_line`.

Comment: I like the idea of writing a `write_char` macro for outputting a single character value. how would it look like?

Comment: Probably the easiest implementation would be to just call `putchar()`.

Comment: nope, I dislike using C functions in my assembly code. If I wanted a C code I could easily write a C code.

Comment: OK, well `putchar` just calls `write`, so you can just re-implement `putchar` yourself if you prefer - it will be very similar to your `write_string` macro except you will need a local char variable.

Comment: After `new_line: db 0xa`
the `message: db 'Displaying 9 stars', new_line` results in the following error when assembling:
`9stars.asm:27: error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses’, does this mean I should find the 64-bit address of the label or perhaps?